# Is there a way to call JobFlowId of a an EMR cluster in another EMR job?

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr, amazon-swf

I am executing a Amazon SWF job on EMR. I would like to use this EMR clusters JobFlowID in another EMR cluster. Currently, to add the jar steps to the EMR cluster I am using

AddJobFlowStepsRequest request = new AddJobFlowStepsRequest(jobFlowId)

How could I use this step in another workflow and call the job flow id of the previous cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass the jobFlowId as a return parameter of your SWF activity. Have a second SWF job listen for jobFlowIds on the second EMR cluster and then execute the code whenever it detects one. You should be able to easily implement this in a workflow worker process.